# how to use constructor in c# main program.cs to inject an interface

Tags: c#

I'm new in programming, I have created an interface which name is `IPointCalculator` I have implemented it in this `class`:

```
public class PointCalculator : IPointCalculator
{
    EnemisEntity enm = new EnemisEntity();
    public int pointCal(string enemyType)
    {
        int point = 0;

        if (enemyType == enm.banzai_Bill)
        {
            point = 200;

        }
        else if (enemyType == enm.beach_koopa)
        {
            point = 400;

        }
        else if (enemyType == enm.big_boo)
        {

            point = 800;
        }

        else if(enemyType==enm.blargg)
        {
            point = 1600;
        }

        return point;

    }
}
```

now in my console application, I want to use it:

```
class Program
{
    IPointCalculator _ipCal;
    Program(IPointCalculator pntCal)
    {

        _ipCal = pntCal;
    }
    public  static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        
    }
}
```

but I cant use _ipCal in my Main, how should I use it here? Is it the right way?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code in your `Main` method you are trying to use and the error message or problem you get.

Comment: Main is a static method, and it MUST be static. Static methods can't use non-static resources out of their scope. How would you expect the operation system to create an instance of the Program class?

Comment: @gunr2171 so how to use interface here?

Comment: @masali off-topic suggestion: use `switch` block instead instead of `if / else-if / else` blocks. [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The goal is to untie / loosely couple the entry point (the actual console application) from what you want it to do (PointCalculator).

Create a wrapper class (MyProgram) so you can inject the implementation. From there, you can look at more advanced options like using a dependency injection tool.

```cs
class Program
{    
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {  
      var instance = new PointCalculator();
      var program = new MyProgram(instance);
   }
}

public class MyProgram
{
   private readonly IPointCalculator _pointCalcuator;

   public MyProgram(IPointCalculator pntCal)
   {
      _pointCalculator = pntCal;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't use the interface in the `Main` method because the method is static. The console app also doesn't know by default that `PointCalculator` is the implementation of `IPointCalculator`.

You can use [Dependency Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1) for this, which is a very common pattern.

It allows you to do the following:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();

       Startup startup = new Startup();
       startup.ConfigureServices(services);

       IServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

       // entry to run app
       serviceProvider.GetService<Runner>().Run();
    }
}
```

```
public class Startup
{
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       services.AddTransient<IPointCalculator, PointCalculator>();
       services.AddTransient<Runner>();
   }
}
```

```
public class Runner
{
    private readonly IPointCalculator _pointCalculator;

    public Runner(IPointCalculator pointCalculator)
    {
        _pointCalculator = pointCalculator;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        // I can use the point calculator!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The newer method is this.
This does not uses startup.cs

```
using Kodiak.Function.CreateUserWithOkta;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(s =>
    {
        s.AddTransient<IMyInterfaceClient, MyInterfaceClient>();

    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```